How do I implement a CustomCoder using the Java Beam SDK for a proto GeneratedMessage class?
Note this question is to monitor our alert system of Apache Beam related questions. It will be answered in a few days.
Background
Apache Beam Coder
A Coder enables Apache Beam to infer how to convert elements to and from byte strings. In Java, there exists a CustomCoder abstract base class that implements all method of a Coder except for its encode and decode methods.
GeneratedMessage
A GeneratedMessage serves as a base class for protobuf generated classes in Java.
Problem domain
In the context of Apache Beam, our Transform may be reading from an API, using a client that returns a protobuf generated class. Emitting the instance of that class may need a Coder enables Apache Beam so that Beam knows how to encode and decode the element in the pipeline.
So, how does one create a Coder for a GeneratedMessage?
